# converting json to python dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert the following json to python dictionary but it converts to a python string. I am only interested in the key for the last date (e.g. 2017-11-02) and '2. Symbol' in the json below which came from alphavantage. I did the following and as you can see, it is stored as a list. How can I store it as a dictionary?

```
>>> import json
>>> test=ts.get_daily('AAPL')
>>> 
>>> s=json.dumps(test)
>>> book=json.loads(s)
>>> book[0]['2017-11-02']['4. close']
'168.1100'
>>> type(book)
<class 'list'>
>>> 


[
  {
    '2017-11-02': {
      '1. open': '15.1800',
      '2. high': '15.1800',
      '3. low': '15.1800',
      '4. close': '15.1800',
      '5. volume': '0'
    },
    '2017-11-01': {
      '1. open': '15.1600',
      '2. high': '15.1600',
      '3. low': '15.1600',
      '4. close': '15.1600',
      '5. volume': '0'
    },
    '2017-06-14': {
      '1. open': '13.4700',
      '2. high': '13.4700',
      '3. low': '13.4700',
      '4. close': '13.4700',
      '5. volume': '0'
    }
  },
  {
    '1. Information': 'Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes',
    '2. Symbol': 'WFAAX',
    '3. Last Refreshed': '2017-11-02',
    '4. Output Size': 'Compact',
    '5. Time Zone': 'US/Eastern'
  }
]
```

Comment: please show us what you have got so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is a list containing two dictionaries. book[0] is a dictionary with keys '2017-11-02', '2017-11-01', and '2017-06-14'. book[1] is a different dictionary, with keys '1. Information', .... So just say

> mydict=book[1]